# Change label for shipping cart display

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, subtotal

I am using magento2.3
I want to change the label of Subtotal to Subtotal(including vat) on shopping cart.
Attaching image link for understanding.
https://prnt.sc/of9a5c

Answer (score 0):

use the following path for change of the label of the subtotal

> Go to Vendor/Magento/Module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

you can find the subtotal here

Comment: Can you plz tell me how to over ride it. i am new in magento.
This file changes the sub total here https://prnt.sc/ofa0m8 and not where i want

Comment: copy the above file and go to the 

app -> design > frontend ->vendor name -> theme name -> Magento_Checkout -> templates -> Cart and past the form.phtml file here and change as per your requirement @Nafisa

Comment: Thanx, But This file changes the sub total here prnt.sc/ofa0m8 and not where i want  https://prnt.sc/of9a5c... I want to change in Summary

Comment: Can u plz help me?

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check the above path for change the text.

Comment: Thanx, now how can i override it. I have that fine already in app/..... folder with some content. now do i need to copy everything? Can i copy only subtoal part?

Answer (score 0):

Create folder in app/design/frontend/[Vendor_name]/[Theme_name]/i18n/en_Us.csv

change the label here

First column Subtotal

second column {Replace with your one}

Then Run Upgrade and deploy commands.

This may help you.

Comment: I want to change at only one place. This changes everywhere

Comment: @Nafisa,then use the below answer that will help you..

Comment: But thats creating issue. i already have the file in app.... folder. If i override it looses previous configuration.
    This is the code which i already have.